# Redirecting to another page automatically?

Tags: asp.net

In my web application i want to redirect to login page, which is in the same folder[admin folder], when i type like
 "xxx.com/admin" it is redirect to login.aspx page which is in admin folder.

for this i place one index.html page and write meta tag code, even though it is not redirect to loginpage. it is going to index.aspx page. shall i have to remove this index.aspx page, i have default page also there in admin folder. can u help me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

This will redirect users to your `loginUrl` if they try to access a protected page when they are not authenticated.

You should probably [read up on Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) in asp.net to get all of the dirty details.

[Here is an explanation](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true) of how you can add additional default documents to IIS.  Default documents are used to try and determine which page a user should be directed to when they don't specify a specific page (your `xxx.com/admin` example)

Comment: Mr Abe Miessler i want admin side, i have to interfaces one is user interface and second one is admin interface when i want to go to admin login i have to type xxx.com/admin/adminlogin.aspx but i want when i type xxx.com/admin it redirect to xxx.com/admin/adminlogin.aspx this is my problem

Comment: In IIS add `adminlogin.aspx` using the method described in the link provided in the last paragraph of my response.

Comment: My application is in online how can i change, how can i go to IIS in online

Comment: @Surya, go to IIS on your web server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS 7.5 take a look at the UrlRewrite 2 Module http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

If you are using IIS 6 you can use the asp.net 2 url rewriting technique, but the xxx.com/admin/default.aspx needs to be physically existing to allow redirects to happen